# Any way to add custom code activities to VS toolbox for any workflow project?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, toolbox

What I would like to achieve is to have 2 tabs with custom code activities added automatically to the toolbox every time a new activity is created in any (workflow) project. Ideally this should be done through some code or installer.
I found a solution using the Visual Studio Integration Package but that one is not suitable for me (as it needs the SDK).

I have also tried using the [IActivityToolboxService](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kushals/archive/2009/09/16/iactivitytoolboxservice.aspx) interface but that worked only for creating the tabs in the toolbox. And I was able to create them only if I (already) had access in toolbox to my custom activities.

Any other ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using VS2010.

Comment: Are you referring to snippets or Components?

Comment: I don't really get what is the problem. Could you clarify what are you trying to achieve please?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to convert a string into code?

Comment: I found the answer to this and it solved my problems at that moment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kushals/2010/03/11/adding-activities-out-of-box-to-the-vs-toolbox/